# Botframework: how to handle long running tasks with a bot?

Tags: c#, botframework

How do I handle a long running tasks on a bot so the client dosnt retry to send the message after 15 seconds again.

I got a bot with the botframework v3 and connect the client with directline

Comment: Have you told your client not to retry commands if the bot is taking a long time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Direct Line** channel connector itself does not retry sending messages.  If it does not receive an ack within 15 seconds of sending a message to your bot, it will throw a **Gateway Timeout**.

If you are using the **DirectLineClient**, you can override the retry policy, ensuring the client does not retry messages:

```
DirectLineClientCredentials creds = new DirectLineClientCredentials(directLineSecret);
DirectLineClient directLineClient = new DirectLineClient(new Uri("https://directline.botframework.com"), creds);
directLineClient.SetRetryPolicy(new Microsoft.Rest.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy(new Microsoft.Rest.TransientFaultHandling.HttpStatusCodeErrorDetectionStrategy(), 0));
```

If you have a long running process, that takes more than 15 seconds, consider queuing the message somewhere, so you can acknowledge the call immediately, then process the message on a background thread.  This is conceptually called **Proactive Messaging**.  More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Edit: This blog post also explains one method for handling long operations within a bot, by using Azure Queue storage and an Azure Function which processes the operation and calls the bot when finished:
[Manage a long-running operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-long-operations-guidance)

Another option is to process incoming messages, or long processing messages, on a background thread.  This experimental sample demonstrates some methods using this design:
[Immediate Accept Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/immediate-accept-adapter/csharp_dotnetcore)

Comment: what is the better options?

Comment: Which option is 'better' is a matter of opinion, and many factors are involved.  Which channel are you using? Is the long running process consistently long running, or just sometimes?

Comment: we run directline and its just sometime the bot needs to analyse stuff

Comment: A better option for long running processes is to queue up the message, acknowledge the call, process the message on a background thread, and send the response as a proactive message.