# Bot Framework resends utterance

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

If an utterance is not handled in a certain amount of time, does the bot framework (v3) automatically resend the users' utterance?

Just experienced a situation where failure to respond to a user quickly, and it appeared to resend the utterance a dozen or more times, cause each one to timeout.

If the utterance is not automatically resent, then have to believe the user was clicking the button rapidly.

Comment: Which channel is this happening on?

Comment: Facebook channel.

Comment: I do not recall ever seeing a case where messenger re-sends a message.  The email channel has built-in retry logic, but i do not think any other channel does.

Comment: Thanks, that means us handling the case where a user "spams" us with 20 button clicks rapidly will resolve this issue.

Comment: Yeah, this is something the bot needs to handle.

Answer (score 0):

The **Bot Connector Services** do no re-send messages if they receive no acknowledgement, but will throw a **Timeout Exception** if a bot takes more than 15 seconds to respond (except the email channel, it will attempt to send three times).

Note: some clients have built in retry policy, that needs to be overridden at the client level.  example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53105588/86646